# How to find out if the user is logged in from Firebase Manual Authentication Or Google Authentication Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

My question is how to find out if a user who is currently signed in has been authenticated using firebase manual sign in or google sign in?

When I tap into the user property of class `FirebaseUser` , when I try to access the providerID, it returns "Firebase" even though I am currently signed in through the Google Sign In provider through Firebase. So, is there any way to find out what provider the user has used for registration of the app?

Thanks a lot for your help. Below is the code that I have already written.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getFirebaseUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    print(user.email);
    return user;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  void startTimer() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      if (getFirebaseUser() != null) {
// I Need to push to the menu screen while providing the parameters so that it can recognise if the user is from Firebase Manual Auth or google sign in provider.
        //print(_user.providerId);
//        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
//            builder: (context)
//            {
//          SideBarLayoutStateful(app: MenuScreen(), isFromGoogleSignIn: ,resultUser: _user, profilePicture: _user.photoUrl,);
//        }
        //));
      }
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'welcome');
      timer.cancel();
    });
  }
```

I Need to push to the menu screen while providing the parameters so that it can recognise if the user is from Firebase Manual Auth or google sign in provider, which effects the content displayed on the menu screen.

Thanks for your help and I appreciate it!
Is this supposed to happen:
[image]

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getFirebaseUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    print(user.email);
    print(user.providerId);
    return user;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the added tag Doug!

Comment: I would fully expect providerID to give you a unique string for each auth provider.  If that's not the case, then it might be a bug.

Comment: @DougStevenson see my edited answer... Is this supposed to happen

Comment: If so, is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: You can file an issue on GitHub. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: I see you've edited the question to add screenshots of text.  Please don't do that - copy the code and text into the question itself so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson is it working for you or is it a problem specific to me?